# RegEx to swap only the first 2 digits of a middle part of a string?

Tags: regex, string, replace, xquery

I seem to have quite a difficult task ahead that I need to solve with xQuery and regular expressions.

The case: I have an ALPHANUMERIC string with a VARIABLE length of 20 to 30 chars where ONLY the FIRST 2 DIGITS of the MIDDLE part (char 5 to char(length-5)) of the string should be SWAPPED and IF there are NO or ONLY 1 digit in this MIDDLE part the 10th and 11th char of the string should be swapped.

So, a few examples:

```
String: abcde12345fghij67890            (more than 1 digit)
Output: abcde21345fghij67890            (swap only first 2)

String: 1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0j1k2l3m4     (more than 1 non adjacent digits)
Output: 1a2b3c5d4e6f7g8h9i0j1k2l3m4     (swap only first 2 of middle part)

String: 34gf7asjkabaa4sfdlencxnkil9qrx  (only 1 digit in middle part)
Output: 34gf7asjkbaaa4sfdlencxnkil9qrx  (so, swap char 10 and 11)
```

My pseudocode is something like this:

```
Function ChangeString(OrgString) 
  NewString:=replace(OrgString, RegEx-1st-digits-in-middle-pattern, RegEx-swap)
  if NewString=OrgString #when there were no 2 digits to swap
    NewString:=replace(OrgString, RegEx-10/11char, RegEx-swap)
  return NewString
```

I reckon there's probably no way to get the whole solution in 1 line, so that's why I came up with the above pseudocode. But what should be the correct find and replace regular expressions?

Thanx in advance!

Edit: I forgot 1 thing in my pseudocode... which is to prevent the swap of the 10/11th char when the first 2 digits of the middle-string are the SAME number...

My pseudocode will of course do this:

```
String: whatever4any4any567whatever
Output: whatever4nay4any567whatever
```

So I need to change the compare to something like this:

```
if count(digits in middlestring) < 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the author of [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html):

```
replace(OrgString, "^(.{5})((.*?)([0-9])(.*?)([0-9])(.*)|(.{6})(.)(.)(.*))(.{5})$",
                   "$1$3$6$5$4$7$8$10$9$11$12")
```

Test: https://regex101.com/r/fM9dP1/3

Comment: Thx CoRoNe!  Didn't know this could be done as a one-liner. The RegEx's are basically the same as Tim's solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your pseudocode:

```
Function ChangeString(OrgString) 
  NewString:=replace(OrgString, "^(.{5})(\D*)(\d)(\D*)(\d)(.*)(.{5})$", "$1$2$5$4$3$6$7")
  if NewString=OrgString #when there were no 2 digits to swap
    NewString:=replace(OrgString, "^(.{9})(.)(.)(.*)$", "$1$3$2$4")
  return NewString
```

**Explanation** of the first regex:

```
^      # Anchor the match to the start of the string
(.{5}) # Match any five characters, save them in backreference $1
(\D*)  # Match any number of non-digits, save in $2
(\d)   # Match exactly one digit, save in $3
(\D*)  # Match any number of non-digits, save in $4
(\d)   # Match exactly one digit, save in $5
(.*)   # Match any number of characters, save in $6
(.{5}) # Match any five characters, save in $7
$      # Anchor the match to the end of the string
```

Test the first regex [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/fM9dP1/1).

Test the second regex [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/fM9dP1/2).

Comment: Tim, thanx for your very helpful solution! Unfortunately my pseudocode did NOT catch this one case that does NOT conform to the original description:  When the first 2 digits in the middle-string are the same number, then NewString = OrgString and the 10th/11th char still get swapped. Which shouldn't be... So now I have to build an extra check to see if the first 2 digits in the middle string are the same... Can this be done in RegEx?

Comment: There seems to be a function `get-matches()`. If you're lucky, it will return the contents of the backreferences individually - then you can check whether the third and fifth group are identical before proceeding. Otherwise it's going to be difficult - XQuery doesn't support [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which would be needed to compare submatches within a match...

Comment: Fixed it!  By using your first pattern in fn:matches() it returns "false" when there are < 2 digits in the middle-string. :-)   A somewhat different solution is to check if the fn:string-length() of your first fn:replace() with replacement-pattern '$3$5' is > 2    Thanx again!!!